# Push'ить не получается

Tags: bitbucket, git

Добрый день всем. Всегда нормально получалось, пока на самом сайте битбакета создал readme для репозитория, после чего с компа не пушится. Вот скриншот. Подскажите, как решать эту задачу?

[image]

Comment: @Etki Спасибо!!! Вы гений!!! Вы спасли мне жизнь!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@bemulima](/users/7998/bemulima)](/users/7998/bemulima)

в удаленной репе присутствуют коммиты, которых у вас нет, т.е. кто-то обновил до вас репу, и гит мудро предостерегает вас от несинхронизированного пуша. Нужно просто не забыть сделать следующее:

```
git pull --rebase
```

> как всегда тишина царствует *22 минуты назад*
>
> задан 42 минуты назад

ну охренеть

> непушится

**ЧАСТИЦА НЕ**

**С ГЛАГОЛАМИ**

**СЛИТНО**

**НЕ ПИШЕТСЯ**

* Пока она не является частью этого глагола. Ой, но тогда же она и сама уже не частица. Такие дела.